# log4j set default log directory

Tags: log4j

My desktop application uses log4j 1.2.17. 
I allow configuration through a properties file, this way users can set as many log outputs they want. 
When in production i have a specific log dir that is under the `/var/myapp/log` directory. 
When in development, i have a specific log dir that is under the `/users/agostino/development/myapp/devenvironment/log` that allows me to easily do automated testing because all the stuff is in one place. 
In the log4j.properties i have a line like this:

```
log4j.appender.default_file.File=example.log
```

Well, as I've said, this should go in the designated log directory that is `/var/myapp/log` when in production or `/users/agostino/development/myapp/devenvironment/log` when i am in development. 
I can only think of doing some search and replace in properties and even so it would be a bit cumbersome. Is there a more clean way to do it?
I don't want to use interpolation, because it should be transparent to the user.

Answer (score 3):

I think that one way to solve the problem is using an argument when the virtual machine starts. e.g.:

```
java -Dcustom.log.file=/var/myapp/log ...
```

And you use that system property in your configuration file. e.g.:

```
log4j.appender.default_file.File=${custom.log.file}/example.log
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it through use of listener.

sample code:

```
public class Log4jListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        System.setProperty("rootPath", context.getRealPath(File.separator));

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }

}
```

in above code,deployed path is set to system property.and it is accessed in log4j.xml using ***${rootPath}***

-- and you have to declare that listener in web.xml

```
<!-- listener to set  deployed path to logger -->
  <listener>
        <listener-class>a.b.c.Log4jListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: Unfortunately my application is a desktop application (just updated the question). Can I adapt this solution to my context?